# Ngx-datatable is not showing the data

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am working on an angular component, I am using *ngx-datatable* for displaying the table data.
The table is not showing the data.

the table :

```
        <ngx-datatable
          class="ngx-datatable"
          [class.table]="currentStyle !== 'listview'"
          [rows]="desigs"
          [messages]="{
            emptyMessage: 'No Data' | translate,
            totalMessage: 'Total' | translate,
            selectedMessage: false
          }"
          [columnMode]="ColumnMode.force"
          headerHeight="auto"
          [rowHeight]="auto"
          footerHeight="auto"
          [limit]="10"
         >
          <!-- Column Definitions -->
          <ngx-datatable-column
            name="#"
            [sortable]="false"
            [resizeable]="false"
            [width]="20"
          >
            <ng-template
              let-value="row"
              let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
              ngx-datatable-cell-template
            >
              {{ rowIndex + 1 }}
            </ng-template>
          </ngx-datatable-column>
          <ngx-datatable-column
            name="{{ 'Name' | translate }}"
            [sortable]="false"
            [width]="80"
          >
            <ng-template let-value="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
              <span>{{ value.name }}</span>
            </ng-template>
           </ngx-datatable-column>
      </ngx-datatable>
```

The data I am passing:

```
 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Manager",
            "created_at": "2021-12-12T15:01:24",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-12T15:01:24"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "supervisor",
            "created_at": "2021-12-12T15:01:42",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-12T15:01:42"
        }
    ]
```

Note1: There is no error in the console even restarting the application.
Note2: The same data can be displayed using a simple table.

[image]

Comment: not used ngx-datatable but a quick glanse at the documentaion, it looks like you are missing the columns added to ngx-datatable that tells what properties to show in each column. Kinda how material table is doing it

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen can u point to it wherein the documentation?

Comment: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/readme/getting-started its shown here in the get started template. So its probably easier to start with the simplest version of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, it was the *NgxDatatableModule* which I forgot to import in the module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DesigsListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DesignationsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
  ],
})
export class DesignationsModule {}
```

After importing the *NgxDatatableModule* it works fine.